# Converting (non-base64) text strings to Base64 images

Tags: javascript, image, base64

So I'm just curious if this capability exists, though it may well not exist. I'm trying to take a string of text like `1` or `2323` and convert it into an image that has the text string as background. Nothing crazy about the image, just a placeholder image from a text string. Does this sort of capability exist? So far, I've only been able to find base64 generators for images that I already had, not images I wanted to generate on the fly.

(Bonus points for a solution in Javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this pretty simply without additional libraries if your browser supports HTML5 canvas.

```js
function getTextImage(text) {
  var c = document.getElementById("canvas");
  var ctx=c.getContext("2d");    
  ctx.font="20px Georgia";
  ctx.fillText(text,10,50);
  var img = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
  return img;
}
    
var yourText = "I'm an image";
document.write('<img src="' + getTextImage(yourText) + '"/>');
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" style="display:none;">
</canvas>
```

Comment: Yeah, that's a nice way to do it too.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I figured it out by combining frameworks. [Placehold.it](http://placehold.it) has the ability to generate a sized image with custom text, and that combined with [the trick outlined in this StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6150289/how-to-convert-image-into-base64-string-using-javascript) does what I need it to in Javascript.